# combine two columns only if both column has value in it

Tags: sql, filter, multiple-columns

I am trying to filter data,
so I have two columns and both can have some value or blank(no space) 
I want to retrieve data only if both the column has value.

```
select CustFName + ' ' + JointCustFName as [BothName]
from table
```

I am getting all the result but I want to avoid null or blank value with this.

For example.

```
CustFName
'John'
'Bishop'
'Mark'

JointCustFName
'Mary'
''(blank)
'Wendy'
```

in this case I only want to see
John Mary
Mark Wendy

because there is no JointCustFName relate to CustFName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a where clause with IS NOT NULL to filter null values and <> ''

```
SELECT CustFName + ' ' + JointCustFName as [BothName]
FROM table
WHERE custFName IS NOT NULL and JointCustFName IS NOT NULL
      and custFNAME <> '' and JointCustFName <> ''
```